# Array of arrays element comparison Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, filter

I have an array which looks like

```
[[1, 2, "2 mins"], [2, 3, "4 mins"], [3, 2, "2 mins"]]
```

How can I filter subarrays so that I get the minimum value at position 2 or in case of equality the array of equal elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ar = [[1, 2, "2 mins"], [2, 3, "4 mins"], [3, 2, "2 mins"]]
p ar.group_by{|sub_ar| sub_ar[1]}.min.last
# => [[1, 2, "2 mins"], [3, 2, "2 mins"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like how the following reads:

```
a = [[1, 2, "2 mins"], [2, 3, "4 mins"], [3, 2, "2 mins"]]

min_val = a.min_by { |e| e[1] }[1]
  #=> 2
a.select { |e| e[1] == min_val }
  #=> [[1, 2, "2 mins"], [3, 2, "2 mins"]]
```